# How to install vmrun on CentOS?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I installed `vmplayer` on CentOS 7.
Should the `vmrun` command be part of the `vmplayer` installation?
I cannot find `vmrun` on my system, and google didn't produce any instructions on how to install `vmrun` on CentOS (or Linux in general).

Answer (score 0):

`vmrun` is included with VMware Workstation and VMware Fusion, but AFAIK it is not included with Player.